# Cannot create a working Git server

Tags: linux, git, connection

I have installed Git on my machine and finished the setup of every thing. Git is working fine locally, but when i try to access it globally always return the following

> fatal: '/Gittest/project.git' does not appear to be a git repository
>    fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.

I can access the server where the repository is identified through ssh connection. and access the files in the Git directory, though i can't set the directory as my remote origin

what should i do?

---

I have used the following command to set remote repository

> git remote add origin svn@192.168.1.60:MDosoky/Gittest/project.git

and I have checked the connectivity from the client by using the following command

> scp  svn@192.168.1.60:MDosoky/Gittest/clientm.txt temp

where clientm is in the same location as project.git

Comment: How did you set the directory as the remote origin?

Comment: git remote add origin svn@192.168.1.60:MDosoky/Gittest/project.git

Comment: Try prepending `ssh://` to it.

Comment: you mean like ssh://svn@192.168.1.60:MDosoky/Gittest/project.git

Comment: what is the actual path of the git repo?? I mean the physical local path on the server.
Also r u sure u have user svn? and it has the correct access rights to this path?

Comment: Yes i had 'svn' user, however I have created new user named 'git' and re initiate the public keys in the authorized_keys in the 'git' user, after that i could successfully access the repo. so i think the problem was in the public keys

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I have entered a wrong public key instead of the user I was working on, the problem is solved by changing the public key in the server file